# What can a questioner do if a well-written question goes almost completely unnoticed?

Tags: discussion

I recently posted a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59235775/pyplot-hist-seemingly-manipulating-my-data) to Stack Overflow, which I think was well-written and thought-out. However, since dozens of questions are posted every minute, I feel like it is getting close to impossible that my question - basically most questions around here for that matter - is going to get enough exposure to have a chance of being answered. Instead it will get stuck at around 5-30 views, and then never to be seen again.

Is there anything a questioner can do about this? I obviously do not want to repost and thereby spam the site. Will reformulating my question "bump" it? Any other options, or is it just plain bad luck if your post gets buried by the acute stream of incoming posts?

Comment: Usually I respond to these with easy fixes: Adding a mcve, posting the code at issue, describing what you already tried. But you seem to have all those already, so I guess you'll need a Python person to give you a closer analysis as to why. Have you tried asking on Meta Stack Overflow?

Comment: Editing will bump it but it has only been a day and people have noticed it, you have two up votes, if it was badly written, you would of received downvotes. It takes the right person to see it, just give it some time or try posing about it on https://meta.stackoverflow.com/ and see if it gives it some exposure.

Comment: Relevant post on MSO: [Best way to draw attention to someone else's good question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265874/best-way-to-draw-attention-to-someone-elses-good-question)

Comment: See also this FAQ post: [How do I get attention for one of my own questions without a good answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7046) (Some of the [questions linked there](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/7046) might be of interest, too.)

Comment: I accepted the edit but opted to avoid using pronouns in the title; just in case somebody objected. But as the OP and the author of the post, you can roll back the edit. There was absolutely nothing wrong in using "his" but we also have users who are not male. Again, I accepted the edit but modified the title to keep everyone happy.

Comment: In all honesty, the answers on the duplicate are pretty poor. The first one is explaining what "bumping" is, well the OP already knows that. The 2nd answer says a user needs to earn rep and set up a bounty, well what if earning 50 rep is really hard and takes a really long time? Martin's link above  has a much better answer IMO.

Comment: IMO you've not provided an MCVE - as it's not complete. You have not provided the data - data1 or data2 - to reproduce this. And so I, as an answerer, have to go and generate some numbers that may or may not exhibit the problems you want solved.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure if this is good advice for Stack Overflow, but whenever I have found a question on EL&U or ELL that needed to attract attention, I would change the question title. Some might call it clickbaiting but if you're clever, the title can be both accurate and eye-catching.

To someone like me, a total ignoramus, the title doesn't arouse my curiosity.

> pyplot hist seemingly manipulating my data

However, the title *is* descriptive and appears to be wholly accurate. Maybe it lacks that element of challenge or fun?

You could also try searching for near duplicates and add their links in your question explaining why their answers do not fit, which will also bump your question on the home page.

Apologies, if I'm talking out of my hat but comments as answers get deleted pretty quickly around these parts :)

Comment: Clickbait titles don’t work on Stack Overflow. Two reasons: (1) It’s hard to come up with clickbait titles for boring old programming questions. (2) Stack Overflow receives thousands of questions per day, so new questions push old questions off the home page so quickly that nobody is baited by titles.